# Angular5: Vendor bundle not getting updated in Jenkins build

Tags: angular, jenkins, webpack, ng-build

I have an `angular5` application, i use `webpack` bundler and `yarn` package manager. I setup the application by running the following commands:

```
yarn global add @angular/cli@latest

yarn
```

It installs `angular-cli`, all the respective dependencies/libraries and link the dependencies. When i run `ng serve` the application works fine, when i run `ng build --aot` the application builds fine and the build runs perfectly too.

But when i run the same commands to run my build using a Jenkins Job like below it's not updating the vendor bundle correctly because of which some parts of the application is not working right, especially `highcharts`

```
yarn global add @angular/cli@latest

yarn

ng build --aot
```

I even tried `ng build --aot --vendor-chunks=true` , still the `vendor.js` and `vendor.map.js` files in my local build and the one on `jenkins` build differ.

I did delete all my node_modules , and ran the above mentioned commands, still no difference. The other big difference i could see is my node_modules on local machine have around 1535 packages and the one on jenkins workspace has only 1505. I verified most of the main packages , especially for `highcharts` & `highmaps`. They do exist though.

What am i missing here ? Is it a parameter issue or some other install-able is missing. I am using `anglar-cli` version 1.7.4, `yarn` 1.6.0 and `webpack` latest version too.

Comment: Is there a chance the files are just being cached in your browser? Is there a reason you aren't running `ng build --prod` instead? It would be better to get the cache busting names. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/build

Comment: No , its not cache. I compared the files side by side and they are different. Also I tried by deleting all the browser history too. Used ng build --prod ,but no difference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ends up being the `angular-highcharts` version. Downgrading it from `5.2.12` to `5.2.1` made it working normally.